# Decimal Numbers in the Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

How do I set up an input field that accepts decimal numbers in the QGIS graphical modeler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just had a bit of a play with this. If you enter a decimal value for the default when setting up the parameter, you can use a decimal for the value when running the model.   [image][image]